# Padding of absolute div interpreted differently in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, absolute

In Internet Explorer 8 and above, and all other browsers, the padding of an absolute div element is not pushing the content down the page when there's a negative margin.

But in Internet Explorer 7, the padding pushes the content down anyway.

This code doesn't use JavaScript.

Here's a screenshot of it working in Internet Explorer 8, Firefox, and Chrome (there's no vertical overflow):

[image]

Here's a gif of the same code running in Internet Explorer 7:

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} 

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#header {
  background: yellow;
  height:50px;
}
#body {
  padding-bottom: 50px; /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;         /* Height of the footer */
  background: green;
}

#body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#main-content-container {
  height: 100%;
}
.inset-boxshadow-and-background {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
#container {
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

```html
<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="header">

  </div>

    <div class="body-parent">
      <div id="body">
        <div id="main-content-container">
          <div class="inset-boxshadow-and-background">
          <!-- Body start -->
          <p>In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the <a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/bottom-footer">full article</a> for all the details.</p>
          <!-- Body end -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div id="footer">

  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

And please no "Internet Explorer 7 is useless" because I'm aware it stinks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    p {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html,
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    /* Core styles */
    .header {
        position: absolute; /* needed for stacking */
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .content {
        position: absolute;/* needed for stacking */
        top:50px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color:red;
    }
    .footer {
        position: absolute;/* needed for stacking */
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        bottom:-50px;
        background-color:aqua;
    }
    #main-content-container {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .inset-boxshadow-and-background {
        background-color: red;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-inner">
        <div id="body">
            <div id="main-content-container">
                <div class="inset-boxshadow-and-background">
                    <!-- Body start -->
                    <p>In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the <a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/bottom-footer">full article</a> for all the details.</p>
                    <!-- Body end -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-inner"></div>
</div>
```

**Update**: the following code works well on my side, please refer to it.

```
<style type="text/css">
    p {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html,
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #container {
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        background-color:red;
    }
    #header {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        width:100%;
        background-color: yellow;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .body-parent {
        margin-top: 50px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px; /* Height of the footer */
        background-color: green;
    }
    #body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 50px; 
    }

    #main-content-container {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .inset-boxshadow-and-background {
        background-color: red;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

</style>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div class="body-parent">
        <div id="body">
            <div id="main-content-container">
                <div class="inset-boxshadow-and-background">
                    <!-- Body start -->
                    <p>In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the <a href="https://matthewjamestaylor.com/bottom-footer">full article</a> for all the details.</p>
                    <!-- Body end -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

The result as below:
[image]

Comment: I'm aware I could have used height:calc(100% - 100px); but I can't get a calc polyfill working for IE7. And if I'm using javascript anyways I might as well keep things light with this one liner.

Comment: Hi @Stuffed Marshmallow, please refer to my update. :-)

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this!

Comment: This is a great workaround. I chose this as the correct answer because it answers my question correctly. It doesn't work for me as well as my method using javascript to adjust the height, because I need the height of #body to be stretched down to the footer for an inset boxshadow I plan on placing there.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with IE 7 and I can produce the issue.

When a static element is given a negative margin on the top/left, it pulls the element in that specified direction.

But if you apply it to the bottom/right, it doesn’t move the element down/right as you might think. Instead, it pulls any succeeding element into the main element, overlapping it.

So because of this reason I think that your footer get pulled 50 px in top direction. It is possible that this is how IE 7 works with negative margin.

You can try to remove it may help you to solve this issue.

Reference:

[The Definitive Guide to Using Negative Margins](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/)

Answer (score 0):

This bizzare IE7-only (IE6 and IE8+ show up fine) is fixable by directly changing any absolutely positioned div with a negative margin and positive padding of the same digits.

Here is the JS:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  $('body').height( $(window).height() - 100 );
};
```

```css
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} 

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#header {
  background: yellow;
  height:50px;
}
#body {
  padding-bottom: 50px; /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;         /* Height of the footer */
  background: green;
}

#body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#main-content-container {
  height: 100%;
}
.inset-boxshadow-and-background {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
#container {
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="header">

  </div>

    <div class="body-parent">
      <div id="body">
        <div id="main-content-container">
          <div class="inset-boxshadow-and-background">
          <!-- Body start -->
          <p>In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Just remove the javascript to make it work in every browser except ie7, and keep the javascript to only run successfully it in IE7.</p>
          <!-- Body end -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div id="footer">

  </div>
</div>

</body>
```